# Under what circumstances does fgetcsv return false?

Tags: php, csv

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) says

> fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, including end of file.

What are "other errors," aside from end of file?

Comment: Maybe if the line is not in proper CSV format.

Comment: There could be a disk failure, or a network failure if the file is on a server.

Comment: file opened in write only mode

Comment: To those voting to close, what would make this a better question?